# Check if MySQL result returning rows

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have following Java code

```
// SELECT
String stringQuery  = "SELECT klucz, itemDATA, itemQTY, itemDUR FROM sellbox WHERE gracz =? "
                    + "ORDER BY czas DESC LIMIT 1";

PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement( stringQuery );
statement.setString( 1, playerName ); 

ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery();
queryResult.first();
```

How to determine if it returned rows or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way -

```
ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery();
if(queryResult.next())
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery();
if (queryResult.next()) {
   // process the data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` provides `next()` to check the next rows. 
using `ResultSet.first()` it self gives false if invalid rows in `ResultSet`

Reference: [ResultSet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29)

So using the same method, you can verify the rows in `ResultSet` without using `ResultSet.next()`